# Use Powershell to simulate right-clicking an Active Directory Group's Properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory, command-prompt

Just for clarification, I want the GUI to appear, like the actual window. This is for a side-project I've been trying to work on for a while now the goal was to make a faster way to link a group of users and folder. Since this is a process focusing on saving time, I wanted to have this method of going straight to the properties without having to actively search out the folder.

- Ask if more info is needed
- Code can be provided (Not sure why you'd need it Id prefer not, but I can be arranged)
- I'd REALLY prefer to not use any kind of outside sources or installs. The main goal was to have this powershell script capable of just being put on any ol' computer and have it work. (Not really any old computer but you get my point)

I looked into `RUNDLL32 dsquery,OpenQueryWindow` as an option, but it didn't give me what I needed.

TL:DR - Pretty much what the title says. I want to be able to run this command and have a specific Security Group's Properties Window appear as if I was in Active Directory myself right clicking on properties.

```
    #######Paths#########
param (
$MYDRIVE_PATH = "\\------\KSD\",
$LOG_FILE_PATH = "C:\Users\Documents\Test_Docs\",
$UserListFile = "C:\Users\Documents\Test_Docs\brenda.txt"
)
##########################

Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
#import-module activedirectory

$LogFile = $LOG_FILE_PATH + "\CreateMyDriveFolderAndPermissions_" + (Get-Date -Format "MM-d-y.h.m.s.ms") + ".log"
$groupRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ListDirectory, ReadData, WriteData, CreateFiles, CreateDirectories, AppendData, ReadExtendedAttributes, WriteExtendedAttributes, Traverse, ExecuteFile, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, ReadAttributes, WriteAttributes, Write, ReadPermissions, Read, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize" 
$InheritanceFlag = ([System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit)
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$ErrorCount = 0
$DestinationCheck = 1
$FolderNameCheck = 1

 ####################################### Option Box #######################################
          [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
          [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

                $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
                $objForm.Text = "Options"
                $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
                $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

                $objForm.KeyPreview = $True
                $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
                    {$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
                $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
                    {$objForm.Close()}})

                $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
                $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
                $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
                $OKButton.Text = "OK"
                $OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
                $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

                $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
                $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
                $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
                $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
                $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close();})
                $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

                $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
                $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
                $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
                $objLabel.Text = "Options:"
                $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

                $objBrenda = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
                $objBrenda.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50)
                $objBrenda.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
                $objBrenda.Checked = $false
                $objBrenda.Text = "Brenda Fernandez"
                $objForm.Controls.Add($objBrenda)

                $objForm.Topmost = $True

                $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
                [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

##############################################################################################

####################################### Destination Box #######################################


            [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
            [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

##### Main Box Creation #####
            $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
            $objForm.Text = "New Folder Destination"
            $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
            $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

            $objForm.KeyPreview = $True
            $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
                {$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
            $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
                {$objForm.Close()}})       
    ###################

##### "Ok" Button Creation #####
            $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
            $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
            $OKButton.Text = "OK"
            $OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close();$DestinationCheck = 0})
            $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
    ###################

##### "Cancel" Button Creation #####
            $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
            $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
            $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
            $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close();[System.Environment]::Exit(0)})
            $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
    ###################

##### Message Right Above Selection Box #####
            $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
            $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
            $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
            $objLabel.Text = "Select a Folder:"
            $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 
    ###################

##### List Selection #####
            $objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
            $objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
            $objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
            $objListBox.Height = 80


    ##### Options for Path #####
            [void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Department")
            [void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Engagement")
            [void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Project")
            [void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Opportunity")
    ###################

            $objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

            $objForm.Topmost = $True

            $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
            [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

          ###Path Creation###
           $MYDRIVE_PATH = $MYDRIVE_PATH + $x
          ###################

          $ParentFolder = $x


################################################################################################



####################################### Name Box #######################################
          [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
          [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

                $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
                $objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
                $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
                $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

                $objForm.KeyPreview = $True
                $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
                    {$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
                $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
                    {$objForm.Close()}})

                $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
                $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
                $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
                $OKButton.Text = "OK"
                $OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close();$FolderNameCheck = 0})
                $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

                $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
                $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
                $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
                $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
                $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close();[System.Environment]::Exit(0)})
                $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

                $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
                $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
                $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
                $objLabel.Text = "Enter File Name:"
                $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

                $objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
                $objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
                $objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
                $objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

                $objForm.Topmost = $True

                $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
                [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

                $FolderName = $x
                #if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($FolderName)){$FolderNameCheck = 1}

                $SecurityName = "US-SG " + $FolderName

################################################################################################



if( $objBrenda.Checked -eq $true )  # Checks if it is a Brenda Fernandez folder and if so adds _QPC to the security group name
{
    $SecurityName = $SecurityName + "_QPC"
}


if($FolderNameCheck -eq 0 -and $DestinationCheck -eq 0 ) #Failsafe to make sure all information has been filled out
{

#####Create Security Group#####
              $Description = $ParentFolder + "\" + $FolderName

              New-QADGroup -Name $SecurityName -samAccountName $SecurityName -Description $Description -GroupScope DomainLocal -ParentContainer "------------"



    ##################################          

      $Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($SecurityName,$groupRights,$InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag,"Allow") #Adds all the security options to the variable $Ar
      $UserFolder = New-Item -Path ('{0}\{1}' -f $MYDRIVE_PATH,$FolderName) -ItemType Directory # Creates New Folder
      $Acl = get-acl -Path $UserFolder.FullName #Finds location of Folder's Security group


      while(1) { #Waits for Security Group to be created and appear in Active Directory

        if(  $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar) -eq $NULL ){ break; }   ########### Once Completed it will set the $Ar to $Acl and break out of the loop
        Start-Sleep -s 1    
      }

      $Acl | Set-Acl $UserFolder.FullName  #####Set security group to user folder

      ##################### Notification Popup ##########################
        [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

        $objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 

        $objNotifyIcon.Icon = "C:\Users\Downloads\success.ico"
        $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info" 
        $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText =  "The folder " + $FolderName + " has been successfully created."
        $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Proccess Complete"

        $objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
        $objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
        Start-Sleep -s 1  
        $objNotifyIcon.Dispose()

     ##############################################################################################

    if( $objBrenda.Checked -eq $true ) 
    {

    $DPText = "US\" + $SecurityName + "_QPC;"
    Add-Content $UserListFile $DPText

    }
} 

if ($ErrorCount -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "Done." -ForegroundColor Green
}
else{
    Write-Host "Done. ($ErrorCount)" -ForegroundColor Red
}

<#
              if(() -ne $Null)
              {
                    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

                    $objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 

                    $objNotifyIcon.Icon = "C:\Users\Downloads\success.ico"
                    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Error" 
                    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText =  "The security group " + $FolderName + " already exists."
                    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Something went horribly wrong!"

                    $objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
                    $objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
                    Start-Sleep -s 1  
                    $objNotifyIcon.Dispose()

                    exit
              }

              #>

#[Windows.Clipboard]::SetText("Meow")
```

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you mean by "link a group of user and folder". What folder are you talking about?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers If I understand correctly, he is trying to create a script that will generate a folder, and then create an AD Security Group for managing user rights to that folder, then setting up the ACLs for that new group on the folder, and finally he wants the group properties GUI to pop up so that it can be populated with users. i.e. Create `\\<server>\Accounting` then create the sec group `fldrAccounting` and grant it rights to `\\<server>\Accounting`. Then pop up the Active Directory Users and Computers Properties window for that group to add users.

Comment: Now, having said that, welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is designed to help troubleshoot issues people having when trying to create code, it is not designed for people to come and just ask for people to write your script for you. If you have tried, and failed, show us what you have done and what errors you are getting and you will be much more likely to get help.

Comment: So I am sent folder request via email, these are requests for folder creations to be put on a shared drive. Now working at the company I do we can't have any old person be able to click on that folder and see the contents. So what we do is created a Security Group in AD and add the desired users to that group. The Security Group is then added to the Security Groups allowed to access the folder in the folder's properties. But the typing and re-typing of names is monotonous, so I've written a script to make, name, the folders and security groups, followed by combining the two together.....

Comment: ....while there are ways for me to add members, I do not trust the senders of the emails, being only human, to send me the correct samaccountname, the first time. So I wanted the GUI to appear because it is much more friendly to work with than an input textbox.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Okay, so what if instead opening a properties menu in AD it did something like  `ii ..\..\windows\system32\dsa.msc` but pathed straight to the Security Group, do you think something like that would be feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting WAY too complicated.  I would try using the ActiveDirectory module installed with RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools).  Don't be afraid to leave the GUI, it's not that scary once you get used to it.   :)

Really, I mean you could probably do this with a one-liner.

Comment: I mean, I know I can, and I am afraid to leave the gui, I was just hoping there'd be a way to avoid it. On top of that I am now officially curious and just want to know if it IS possible. It seems like the right-click properties is just a link/path to some sort of hidden gui menu or something.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  I would get that security object into a variable and check its members with Get-Member.  The GUI is calling a method to an object, you just have to find the right one.  I would start with your target (the security object) and work your way through its parents and children.

Comment: Good call on this one. I was just about to point him in the same direction. I think you are relying on a GUI too much for something you are trying to script. Either script it, or don't. If you don't trust your data make your script catch errors and display a list of users that weren't valid or something.

Comment: Oh, and yes it is a link to something hidden. A COM object created in C# or something. See [http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Active+directory/Part+III+Scripting+Active+Directory+with+ADSI+ADO+and+WMI/Chapter+24.+Extending+the+Schema+and+the+Active+Directory+Snap-Ins/24.2+Customizing+the+Active+Directory+Administrative+Snap-ins/](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Active+directory/Part+III+Scripting+Active+Directory+with+ADSI+ADO+and+WMI/Chapter+24.+Extending+the+Schema+and+the+Active+Directory+Snap-Ins/24.2+Customizing+the+Active+Directory+Administrative+Snap-ins/) for info